# sed pattern replace, trailing spaces ending with + only with +

Tags: sed

sed pattern replace, trailing spaces ending with + only with +

**input**

```
Summary of differences with Numeric          +34
First-step changes     +34
```

**output**

```
Summary of differences with Numeric+34
First-step changes+34
```

Did not find [answer here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dos this work for you?

```
sed 's/ *+/+/'
```

add `g` if you want to multi-replacements in line.

Comment: This will always replace `+` with `+` and so may not replace trailing spaces followed by `+` if `+` occurs beforehand. If you want to replace the first occurrence of the pattern above use: `sed 's/  *+/+/' file`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's|\s+([+]\S+)$|\1|' file
```

Output:

```
Summary of differences with Numeric+34
First-step changes+34
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example do:

```
$ sed -r 's/\s{2,}\+/+/g' file
Summary of differences with Numeric+34
First-step changes+34
```

This removes multiple spaces (at least 2) whenever they are followed by the `+` character. Note `+` has to be escaped to be interpreted as character and not as a regex symbol.

Comment: Tnx, but need better solution, only where +es are present.

Comment: Oh now I see I missed a \ to escape the `+`.